# Jscrollpane z-index issue

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, jscrollpane, jquery-chosen

I'm using `Jscrollpane` + `jquery-chosen` but as you can see the chosen menu is hidden under Jscrollpane box.

I think the issue with `z-index`.
I tried a lot of changes but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

it is because of overflow:hidden property for .tickets-content class remove it and it will work

it has both inline and external styles in style.css (#page-events .tickets-content{})

Comment: Thank you, Is there another way to fix it, because it will make `Jscrollpane` useless

Comment: The inline style is from `Jscrollpane` to make it work

Comment: you will use both the scroller vertical as well as horizontal?

Comment: I don't want to use both scrolls, I just want to display the chosen menu without affecting the `Jscrollpane` behavior. Also I can add extra padding to the last row and the problem will be solved but I want something other than this.

Comment: i didn't understand why 'jscrollpane' is use?

Comment: To Change the scroll-bar styles, check the demo: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html I'm applying custom styles if you can notice that.

Comment: I know that but this plugin gives two options horizontal scroll and vertical scroll in horizontal scroll overflow-x: scroll can be used as an option and for vertical scroll overflow-y: scroll can be used

Comment: if you are using vertical scroll anything which is overlapping in x will be show if overflow-y:scroll is used